# Reset product quantities in shopping lists after order placed

Tags: orocommerce

I want to know if it is possible to automatically reset the product quantities in shopping lists after customer places the order?

Not the order, but the shopping list itself.

Eg. Change from 5 back to 1?

Comment: Hi. The requirement doesn't sound clear to me. Please clarify the question. Do you want to change the shopping list left after placing the order or the quantity in the order itself? And how do you want to do that, from the storefront or the management console UI or automatically?

Comment: Hi. Sorry I should of clarified. Automatically change the shopping list itself after the customer finishes an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it as a part of the custom checkout workflow based on one of the default workflows. For more details the [documentation](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/entities-data-management/workflows/intro/#backend-workflows-intro).

For example, that change can be a workflow action described in the last workflow transition definition and executed when the order is created.